# Why this snippet of code isn't generating all the permutations?

Tags: c++, permutation

For input string "bba", it's not generating all the integer permutations.
The integers that will be stored in the array are: 2, 1, 1

The output is 2 1 1.

I want the output to be:

1 1 2

1 2 1

2 1 1

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin >> s;
    int ss = s.size();
    int ar[ss];
    for(int i=0; i<ss; i++) {
        int tmp = int(s[i])-96;
        ar[i] = tmp;
    }  

    do {
        for(auto i: ar) std::cout << i;
        std::cout << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(ar, ar+ss));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically your program isn't valid, since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). And why don't you simply permutate `s` directly?

Comment: As for your problem, if you read between the lines of e.g. [this `std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) (as well as see the example) you should know that the container you permutate needs to be *sorted*.

Comment: Lastly, I suggest you read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: include <algorithm> instead.

Comment: Avoid magical number as `96`, use `'a' - 1` instead.

Comment: Okay, I won't use magic-constants anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting only one permutation is because there's no permutation lexicographically greater that the current state of array: `[2, 2, 1]`. See the documentation of [`std::permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

> Transforms the range [first, last) into the next permutation from the
>   set of all permutations that are lexicographically ordered with
>   respect to operator< or comp. Returns true if such permutation exists,
>   otherwise transforms the range into the first permutation (as if by
>   std::sort(first, last)) and returns false.

Consider using `std::vector` instead of C-array and sorting it before calculating all the permutations:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s = "bba";
    const int ss = s.size();
    std::vector<int> ar;
    ar.reserve(ss);
    constexpr int offset = 'a' - 1;
    for(int i=0; i<ss; i++) {
        int tmp = int(s[i]) - offset;
        ar.push_back(tmp);
    }  
    std::sort(ar.begin(), ar.end());
    do {
        for(auto i: ar) std::cout << i;
        std::cout << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(ar.begin(), ar.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
122
212
221
```

<kbd>[**Live example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vtsCAGBFJMFqJicf)</kbd>

**Update**: as it was pointed out by @Someprogrammerdude, please see: [`Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

**Update 2**: as it was pointed out by @Jarod42 consider using `'a' - 1` instead of magic-constant `96`.

Answer (score 2):

Making an array of Integers before generating permutations seems unnecessary.
You are missing a point where you sort your values.

Try this approach instead:

```
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
do {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        std::cout << int(s[i]) - 96 << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
} while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

The output is

```
1 2 2                                                                                                                                                                                       
2 1 2                                                                                                                                                                                       
2 2 1
```

Comment: Yes, i was missing sorting.